# Retrieve element from inner array in array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way to retrieve an element from inner array in array when using nested lodash find, for example?

I have an array of groups, each element of which has array of children. All children have unique ids (even between groups).
I need to get hold of a child with id == value and now I'm doing the following:

1. Firstly I retrieve needed group:

   `var group = _(groups).find(g => {return _(g.children).find(c => {return c.id == value})});`
2. Then I get the child:

   `var child = _(group.children).find(c => {return c.id == value});`

Is there a more efficient and elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: why lodash? native javascript (filter(), map(), etc) are not enough?

Comment: no idea, we just use it in our project :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flat groups by children and find from result

```
_(groups)
    .flatMap('children')
    .find({id: value})
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a another way of doing this using map() and filter()

```
var filteredArray = [];

_.map(group, function(groupValue) {
  var groupChildren = groupValue.children;
  var filteredChild = _.filter(groupChildren, function(child) {
    return child.id = value
  });
   if(filteredChild.length != 0) {
     filteredArray.push(filteredChild[0]);
     return groupValue;
   } else {
     return groupValue;
   }
});
```